# apt-get update warning: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package…

Tags: 14.04, apt

*<sup>This had a bounty on it, it was not awarded as there was no good answer… ☹</sup>*

---

I tried running `apt-get update` and got these warnings:

```
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max                                                                            
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min                                                                            
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max                                                                           
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min                                                                                                                                                   
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

As instructed, I tried `apt-get update` again and got the same warnings.

**What can I do to fix those?**

Full output follows:

```
    ; sudo apt-get update                                                          
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                     
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources               
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                 
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources               
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages              
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages          
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages               
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages         
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages           
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
    Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                               
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                             
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                    
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources              
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources                
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources              
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages             
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages         
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages              
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages        
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages          
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages        
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en             
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en         
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                  
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources              
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages           
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages      
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages        
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages      
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en           
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en       
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                 
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                      
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                        
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                      
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages               
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                 
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages               
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                      
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                  
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                  
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                     
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en               
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB            
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en               
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_GB              
    Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                 
    Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB.UTF-8            
    Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB.UTF-8      
    Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB.UTF-8      
    Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_GB.UTF-8      
    Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
    Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
    Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max                                                                               
    Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min                                                                               
    You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems                    
    Reading package lists... Done                                                   
    W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max                                                                             
    W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min                                                                             
    W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max                                                                            
    W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min                                                                            
    W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I removed all external PPA, yet still get this error: *therefore this is not a duplicate of [Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 successful, but it failed actually?](https://askubuntu.com/q/818174/24976)*

More debugging based on comments:

```
; apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main i386 Packages
     release o=apt.postgresql.org,a=precise-pgdg,n=precise-pgdg,l=PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository,c=main
     origin apt.postgresql.org
 500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
     release o=apt.postgresql.org,a=precise-pgdg,n=precise-pgdg,l=PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository,c=main
     origin apt.postgresql.org
 500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release o=Node Source,n=trusty,l=Node Source,c=main
     origin deb.nodesource.com
 500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Node Source,n=trusty,l=Node Source,c=main
     origin deb.nodesource.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-neovim-ppa-unstable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Neovim Unstable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-neovim-ppa-unstable,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Neovim Unstable,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.6/main i386 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.6,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.6/main amd64 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.6,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.5/main i386 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.5,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.5/main amd64 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.5,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty/main i386 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release n=llvm-toolchain-trusty,c=main
     origin llvm.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=precise,n=precise,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=precise,n=precise,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-certbot-certbot,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Certbot PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-certbot-certbot,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Certbot PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en_GB
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en_GB
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
; apt libapt-pkg\*
E: Invalid operation libapt-pkg*
```

Although, I suspect this might be more relevant:

```
; apt-cache policy python-cffi-backend-api-max python-cffi-backend-api-min
python-cffi-backend-api-max:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-cffi-backend-api-min:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add **fully** output of `sudo apt update` \\ Do you use any ppa ?

Comment: @ali76 Added the full output. Yes, I do use several `ppa`…

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have? Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems to have repos for trusty, which is Ubuntu 14.04.  Have you recently upgraded to a newer version?

Comment: @Katu Version is 14.04 as tagged. It was upgraded from 12.02 ages ago but not since then and the message is recent -- last two weeks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt --version`, `apt-cache policy apt libapt-pkg\*`? Thanks.

Comment: I would like to see the output of `apt-cache policy python-cffi-backend-api-max python-cffi-backend-api-min`, since they are the offending packages. My guess is that they are from an unofficial source such as a PPA.

Comment: I want to stress, by the way, that the problem is with *those two packages only*, not with Apt or with any other package.

Comment: Okay, the packages are not actually installed, nor are they present in the official repositories, so as I said elsewhere they are probably leftovers from the PPAs you have removed. Try cleaning your Apt cache; I don't remember how to do that but your favourite search engine does.

Comment: @fkraiem There is a package called `python3-cffi-backend` and that is installed. Running `sudo apt-get clean` did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It is possible that `python3-cffi-backend` is the culprit, then, because it is not officially available for Trusty.

Comment: It is needed by [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)… Opened [issue 5063](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5063).

Comment: You ask if there is a solution. Yes, there is: whoever provides the version of `python-cffi-backend` you are using needs to fix their packaging. (The issue is only in the packaging, not in the software itself.)

Comment: @fkraiem Feel free to write up an answer and you can have lots of fake internet points.

Comment: Can you confirm that uninstalling the package solves the issue?

Comment: @fkraiem Nope. Removing both the PPA and the package does not help the problem. ☹

Comment: Okay... Try `apt list --installed | grep -v trusty`; this will list all installed packages which are not in your current Trusty repos, the culprit should be among them.

Comment: Ran `apt list --installed | /bin/grep -v trusty | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | xargs apt-cache depends | /bin/grep -i cffi` which returned nothing. Bah. ☹

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real solution appears to track down the offending package and ask the PPA maintainer to fix it.

Since the issue happened because of `certbot`, I opened [issue 6063](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5063) to tackle this. This [comment](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5063#issuecomment-327625582) asked the maintainer of the PPA to fix the problem.

As off Monday 23 October, this **has been resolved.** Make sure you do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To get the changes.

Answer (score 21):

This problem happens because your version of apt is "too old" and doesn't support packages that use versioned "Provides:".

You can check your apt version with

```
apt --version
```

"versioned provides" were added in apt 1.0.7, but Ubuntu 14.04 ships with apt 1.0.1.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1662227
for more information.

The warning is harmless. If you really want to remove it, you can compile apt from sources to a version that supports versioned provides.

**Warning!:** Updating apt is potentially dangerous and can break the package manager.

If you choose to do it, follow these steps:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150821T213547Z/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.10.2.tar.xz
tar -xvf apt_1.0.10.2.tar.xz
cd apt-1.0.10.2
./configure
make
```

Comment: So, the official way to get packages on Ubuntu 14.04 is broken with official 14.04 packages… Words fail me…

Comment: @Sardathrion the message is a warning, it's not broken.

Comment: Generally it is not safe to ignore warnings: They are there to warn you that something *is amiss* in the system. What happens when a security package does not install because of it? You are left with a vulnerable machine that will get a root kit or ransom ware…

Comment: -1 for the suggestion to update Apt.

Comment: @fkraiem I did not recommend to do this. I put it as the only way I know of removing the warning. I deliberatively said "compile" instead of "update" and I didn't include the `sudo make install` command at the end of the instructions.

Comment: @Sardathrion I think my answer provides an explanation of the problem and it also gives you a solution for it. Can you tell me why is not good?

Comment: While it provides an explanation, I am neither able to verify that it is correct nor use it to solve my concrete problem. The solution given is unsafe and might result in trashing the machine. Hardly a good outcome.

Comment: @Sardathrion OK, I respect your opinion. For this and other potentially dangerous changes, I would recommend to test them in a Virtualbox. You can verify them that way.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a good way to test it. Sadly, I cannot spare the hours it would take to do so. ☹

Comment: Oh, clearly, I very much appreciate the time you took to write your answer and give you help. Nothing I say should be read as ungrateful. I am grateful for yourself and @fkraiem.