# Safe way to upgrade apt

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

Based on this question: [apt-get update warning: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package…](https://askubuntu.com/q/946402/24976), it appears that updating `apt-get` to a version upwards of 1.0.7 is required.

This concerns me greatly. First, doing the upgrade in the "good old way" of `make && make install` is probably going to cause more trouble than it is worth. This is why everyone has moved away from that method. Second, manually updating is a pain (see point above) and I would rather use a `PPA` if there was one. However, I cannot find it. Thirdly, and probably more importantly I wonder if it is a safe thing to do.

*Is there a safe way to update `apt`?*

Comment: Apt is an essential system component; tinkering with it is asking for trouble.

Comment: By the way, you definitely should not be getting these warnings, as of course all the packages in the Trusty repositories should work with the version of Apt in Trusty. Maybe there is some leftover package information from the PPAs you have removed.

Comment: @fkraiem I know I should not be getting those warnings! What I was asking [here is how to fix it!](https://askubuntu.com/q/946402/24976). The only answer is "update apt". If you have a better idea, please let me know, and earn yourself +50 rep.

Comment: In any case, do not update Apt, you'll just make things worse.

Comment: @fkraiem Can you write an answer based on your last comment and I will give you lots of fake internet points.