# W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal

Tags: 14.04, linux-headers

When running `sudo apt-get update` below warnings are displayed in console

```
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal 
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal 
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/946402/apt-get-update-warning-ignoring-provides-line-with-depcompareop-for-package